# Как разместить элемент внутри flex блока в крайнюю правую часть?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Вот codepan codepen.io/Spawnes/pen/ZEopwRZ

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.item {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так: чтобы блок №3 прижался к блоку №4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлять новые элементы или классы нельзя.
Вопрос именно в том, чтобы сделать это исключительно стилями с такой вёрсткой.

Comment: Обернуть 3 и 4 в еще один элемент нельзя?

Comment: В этом вся загвоздка, нет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно сделать так: чтобы блок №3 прижался к блоку №4

**Вариант 1**

Можно их "обернуть" еще одним элементом...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.item {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div id='box'>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**

Можно второму добавить еще описание отступов по краям...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.item {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.test {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, менять вёрстку нельзя. 
Добавить класс можно. 

Но, всё-таки интересно, можно ли это сделать не меняя вёрстку совсем и не добавляя классы. Только стилями.

Comment: @Spawnes во втором варианте можно изменить селектор и класс не потребуется: `.container div:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Да, пожалуй, это будет лучшим вариантом. 
Проблема лишь в том, что если добавится ещё один элемент между ними, тогда нарушится последовательность. 
Тогда нужно как-то считать "второй элемент с конца"

Comment: @Spawnes, что бы выбрать "второй элемент с конца" можно использовать `:nth-last-child`, но при большем количестве элементов нужно будет добавить margin во все элементы, а в последних двух обнулить. Пример: https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/VwBdbjr

Answer (score 0):

Способ не правильный конечно из соображения того, что 4 элемент может менять свою ширину.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 47px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, такой вариант точно не подойдёт. Но спасибо за активность. 
Там ниже уже дали ответ.

Comment: Так вы ж сказали нельзя менять html разметку))

Comment: Там есть второй вариант, где вёрстка не меняется, а элемент находится с помощью nth-child(2) и добавляются по бокам margin: auto